# upgrade from WPMU 2.9.2 to WP 3.2.1

Tags: multisite

I am running WPMU 2.9.2 and want to update to WP 3.2.1.

As I understand it, WP 3 took in WPMU.  I imagine that involved some big changes to the implementation of WPMU.  What steps do I need to take to perform the upgrade?

Thank you.

Pat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The codex has some very detailed advice: [Upgrading_WPMU](http://codex.wordpress.org/Upgrading_WPMU). Make sure to test it on a safe copy of the real site.